# android Room + livedata + observer onChaged working logic and issues (called more than once under specific actions)

Tags: android, mvvm, fragment

I have an android app built following the MVVM pattern. Everything is working perfectly and i really like the new livedata feature. However, I am stuck trying to figure out why I see this strange behavior with a specific class in my app.
I have this code:

```
public class MyFragment1 extends LifecycleFragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.mtitle);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);

        RecyclerView listView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        listView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        listView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new RoutesAdapter(new ArrayList<>());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Log.i(TAG, "Fragment OBSERVER count: " + getLifecycle().getObserverCount());
        observer = (items) -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "CHANGED OBSERVED");
                adapter.setItems(items);

            Log.i(TAG, "Fragment OBSERVER count: " + getLifecycle().getObserverCount());
            Log.i(TAG,"getItems() HAS OBSERVERS:"+mViewModel.getItems().hasObservers());
        };
        mViewModel.getItems().observe(this,observer);

        listView.addOnItemTouchListener(new MRecyclerTouchListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), listView, new MRecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                item =  adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                MenuBottomSheetFragment mBottomSheetDialog = MenuBottomSheetFragment.newInstance();
        mBottomSheetDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MenuBottomSheetFragment");
            }
        }));
        return view;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a method `getItems()` which returns a `LiveData<List<>>` (I am using `Room` library, so `getItems` fetches from the database and returns a LiveData list object).
So far so good! Clicking on an item, I open a bottom sheet dialog fragment with options for the selected item. This is created using an inner `static` class as shown below:

```
public static class MenuBottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

public MenuBottomSheetFragment(){}

public static MenuBottomSheetFragment newInstance(long routeId, Date timestart, Date timeend, long duration, double distance, String uid, long syncid) {
    MenuBottomSheetFragment frag = new MenuBottomSheetFragment();
    return frag;
}

@Override
public void setupDialog(final Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    MyViewModel mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
    View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.bottom_sheet, null);
    dialog.setContentView(view);

    TextView txtView = (TextView)view.findViewById( R.id.txt_view);

    txtView.setOnClickListener((v)-> {
        this.dismiss();
        ViewFragment rvf = ViewFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.flContent, rvf, "ViewFragment");
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    });
}
}
```

My activity handles 6 different fragments (based on the selection from the drawer, replaces the current fragment with the selected). Replacing a fragment with the one above (MyFragment1) from the activity, the observer is registered once and works perfectly well (even if selecting it again from drawer while visible, because it goes through the onDestroy - removing the observer - and recreating it).
The problem shows up when the user clicks the `txtView`. This action will replace `MyFragment1` with `ViewFragment`. When the user hits the back button, android goes to `MyFragment1` again but now it creates two observers and it keeps creating while user is going back and forth between these 2 fragments (Log messages show # OBSERVER count, instead of only 1 even if there are no changes to trigger the observer).

Now, I have read the docs and went through the code of `LiveData.java` and `LifeCycleRegistry.java` and noticed two things:

1. `mViewModel.getItems().hasObservers()` returns always `false` which means that calling `observe()` never adds it to the observer list
2. However, `getLifecycle().getObserverCount()` is increasing as many times as `observe()` is getting called (i.e going back to the fragment from another fragment)

Question 1
Why `LiveData hasObservers()` returns false, while the observer count of the owner (fragment) seems to have observers (`LifeCycleRegistry.java`)? 
As I understand it, by reading the code, to add the observer to the owner means that first should add the observer to the `Livedata` observer list using a method `putIfAbsent` which searches for the object if already exists (it passes the edge conditions and the `if` checks, adds it to the local observer list variable if it does not exist and then to the owners observer list). Otherwise it returns before adding anything.

Question 2 (Relative to 1)
It says in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observe(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20android.arch.lifecycle.Observer%3CT%3E))

> if the given owner, observer tuple is already in the list, the call is ignored.

The way it seems to work right now, is that `observe()` never adds to the list the call (one thing can happen here: 1) already added in the observe list (unlikely to be that at least the first time) and if this somehow is the reason, then it should return before adding it to the lifecycle owner observer list (because it already exist.. right?), but somehow the counter of the owner's list is increasing every time.
What is happening?

Going through the `LiveData.java` code and `observe()` method you will see that this method is responsible for adding the observable object into the LiveData's observer list and also creates a wrapper of this object and adds it into the owner's lifecycle observer list. Right now I believe it's happening only the second (because of the counter) but haven't figured out why yet.

Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to Question No. 1:

It seems, that you are observing the wrong LiveData by creating new Instances of your LiveData every time you update your LiveData in your ViewModel. You must return the same Instance of LiveData to be able to observe it and to check if it has Observers.

For example in your ViewModel:

```
private LiveData<List<Items>> liveItems;

public void initItems(){
    liveItems = wherever you get your Data;
}

public LiveData<List<Items>> getItems() {
    return liveItems;
}
```

then you can observe LiveData in your Fragment with:

```
mViewModel.getItems().observe(this, observer)
...
```

then, when you call:

```
mViewModel.getItems.hasObservers()
```

it will return true.

Comment: Hey @borgwald, I guess you were right.. My mistake was that the method inside my view model was returning the livedata object directly without initializing it once in a list and return the list instead (example follows) `public LiveData<List<MObject>> getRoutes() { return db.getDatabase().mDao().getList();}` . Replacing this code with the return of a local list initialized once worked. Thanks.